# ResXFileCodeGeneratorEx Project not building in VS2022

Tags: c#, asp.net, com, resx

I cloned this repository and tried to build in Visual Studio 2022: https://github.com/cpaton/ResXFileCodeGeneratorEx

I am trying to build this in Visual Studio 2022 (Community edition), but the build is not working.

Hello,

I cloned this repository and tried to build in Visual Studio 2022: https://github.com/cpaton/ResXFileCodeGeneratorEx

I am trying to build this in Visual Studio 2022 (Community edition), but the build is not working and I am getting this below error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       CreatePkgDef : error : ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.CreatePkgDef.ProcessAssembly(String fileName, Hive hive, PkgDefContext context, Boolean register, RegistrationMode mode)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.CreatePkgDef.DoCreatePkgDef(InputArguments inputArguments)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.CreatePkgDef.Main(String[] arguments)
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop, Version=7.1.40304.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop, Version=7.1.40304.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.    ResXFileCodeGeneratorEx         

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The "ResolveComReference" task returned false but did not log an error. ResXFileCodeGeneratorExPackage          

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     Cannot find wrapper assembly for type library "Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandBars". Verify that (1) the COM component is registered correctly and (2) your target platform is the same as the bitness of the COM component. For example, if the COM component is 32-bit, your target platform must not be 64-bit.   ResXFileCodeGeneratorExPackage          


Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     The "ResolveComReference" task returned false but did not log an error. ResXFileCodeGeneratorExPackage          


Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     The referenced component 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandBars' could not be found.   ResXFileCodeGeneratorExPackage          


Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     The referenced component 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandBars' could not be found.   ResXFileCodeGeneratorExPackage
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfT02.png)

Not sure what is the issue. I simply cloned and trying to build to generate the vsix. Alternatively, if it builds on your machine could you please share the vsix. All I need is vsix.

**EDIT**

I already have the Visual Studio extension SDK installed:

[VS Extension SDK][1]

I have set all projects to Any CPU:

[Debug is set to Any CPU and same is in Build][2]

Yet I keep getting the errors.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFP6a.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJin4.png

Comment: Remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandBars from references. Install the Visual Studio SDK https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/visual-studio-sdk?view=vs-2022 Build in "Any Cpu" configuration only

Comment: @SimonMourier Thank you but that doesn't work. Please check my edit. Alternatively, I request you if it builds on your machine could you please share the debug folder of all projects via Dropbox link or something.

Comment: Not sure where does that requirement for Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop, Version=7 comes from, it's an old thing. Try to update all nuget packages for the solution, also try to 1) close VS 2) delete all bin & obj directories 3) restart VS 4) build.

Comment: @SimonMourier Tried those already and didn't find a solution.

Comment: Do you have a place where I can drop the vsix

Comment: @SimonMourier Wow - did you already have the vsix? Could you please post your source code and the vsix. The link is this: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/hpemtrsfcryu2yimmvbem/h?dl=0&rlkey=8ewsnt6uleh499gkq14x64seb Please create a demo dropbox account and you should be able to paste it in there. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Like I said, it should work. I've put a .zip in there

Comment: @SimonMourier: Thank you for uploading but when I build I get the same error: https://gyazo.com/fa1e4c4f32f3cadcda83675f37fdcef5 All I did was download your zip and open in VS2022 Community and Build and get this. So then I went in your Bin Debug folder as I can see you were able to successfully generate .vsix. I installed the Vsix extension but it doesn't seem to work. I updated the Custom Tool Name to ResxCodeFileGeneratorEx2022 https://gyazo.com/50b12e8bd0f1b3d778926ac72f9e83d4 When I click on RunCustom Tool I get the error: https://gyazo.com/8cac1b71540320f1e3f2633f0091eb77

Comment: @SimonMourier But infact that tool does exist: https://gyazo.com/090ad9103a9b2b4237d0e48ae5f449ea as I had just installed using your vsix so my only question is when you run on some resx do you get the .cs file generated or you get the same error as mine? I forgot to mention - you are very helpful :)

Comment: I don't have "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop, Version=7.1.40304.0" which is weird.

Comment: @SimonMourier I also tried to change the custom tool name to ResxCodeFileGeneratorEx instead of ResxCodeFileGeneratorEx2022 because in VS2019 I have ResxCodeFileGeneratorEx and it seems to work using a different .vsix but that did not make a difference here. I keep getting custom tool does not exist.

Comment: @SimonMourier Also something to note - may be related or may be not but all the previous vsix size were in KBs whilst yours is very large around 71MB https://gyazo.com/c585c01404bc3e72d345da0a6af5b587